# Cross-compiling Rust on Win10 for aarch64/Linux

Tags: windows, rust, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile for a 64-bit ARMv8 / Raspbian (DietPi actually), from Windows, but I'm getting a series of issues with 3rd-party crates.

**What I installed**

- rust toolchain 1.61.0
- ARMv8 gcc toolchain ([from here](https://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry64/))
- MS Visual Studio 2019 C++ build tools ([from here](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/0af00169-b3da-4369-a810-69b1c655d105/a610564bf5e214bc49c6a58e93c7a24d0ce49b1ffaec5fa957e2c8101f368ae2/vs_BuildTools.exe))
- (IntelliJ IDEA UE and the IntelliJ plugin - FYI but not really relevant to the question)

From there it is possible to add the required target - note that it's dependent on the ARM gcc toolchain (for example the 32-bit version is armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf):

```
rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then I edited `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config` and added those lines:

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc.exe"
```

And finally, I added those to the `PATH`:

- %USERPROFILE%\.cargo\bin
- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin (for **cmake**)
- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin (for **msbuild**)
- [ARMv8 gcc toolchain]\bin

**How I cross-compiled**

After making sure everything was compiling and running correctly for Windows, I tried to cross-compile:

```
cargo build -r --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

**The problem I have**

While this worked for simple applications, it quickly becomes clear that many crates fail to compile. For example, `freetype-sys`, which is a dependency of `plotters` that I'm using:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `freetype-sys v0.13.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\projects\rust\humidity\rh\target\release\build\freetype-sys-4feef64f7ae6c484\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout

[...]
  
  running: "cmake" "[...]\\freetype-sys-0.13.1\\freetype2" "-DWITH_BZip2=OFF" "-DWITH_HarfBuzz=OFF" "-DWITH_PNG=OFF" "-DWITH_ZLIB=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\\projects\\rust\\hum
idity\\rh\\target\\aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu\\release\\build\\freetype-sys-3464f88f9fbe3bc0\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= 
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "D:/projects/rust/humidity/rh/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/freetype-sys-3464f88f9fbe3bc0/out/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

  --- stderr
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:119 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.462+g62fb89029d for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 11/06/2022 11:53:19.
      Project "D:\projects\rust\humidity\rh\target\aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu\release\build\freetype-sys-3464f88f9fbe3bc0\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.13.19031502-MSVC_2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(378,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build usin
g the v141 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2017 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\p
rojects\rust\humidity\rh\target\aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu\release\build\freetype-sys-3464f88f9fbe3bc0\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.13.19031502-MSVC_2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
      Done Building Project "D:\projects\rust\humidity\rh\target\aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu\release\build\freetype-sys-3464f88f9fbe3bc0\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.13.19031502-MSVC_2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

A previous crate required the path to 2019 MSBuild.exe, hence the extra PATH earlier which solved that problem.

This one seems to require MS VS 2017 build tools. This is getting desperate, so I think the problem is coming from something else.

**What else I have tried**

EDIT1:

I noticed that the Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9) ([here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202017)) include a cross-compiler to ARM64. So

- I installed this version
- launched the (somewhat hidden) vcvarsamd64_arm64.bat script to setup the environment
- replaced the `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc.exe` executable in `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config` with `cl.exe` which is the MS compiler/linker.
- from the project directory, `cargo clean`
- `cargo build -r --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`

It compiles much faster than the gcc toolchain, but it fails compiling the freetype crate:

```
Compiling freetype v0.7.0
error: could not find native static library `freetype`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?
```

Same result with the gcc toolchain and MS VC 2017.

**Question: What exactly is required to cross-compile to this target? Am I missing something?**

- do I need to install several versions of VS build tools? I imagine they'll conflict if they're all in the `PATH`
- do I need to install cmake separately, instead of using the one available in VS? (see PATH defined earlier with CMake)
- is it simply not possible from Windows?

EDIT2: I'm starting to believe that the `freetype` create, which hasn't been updated for a few years and is still in version 0.7.0, cannot be cross-compiled for some reason.

**UPDATE**: I worked around the problem by replacing `plotters` with something else. It removed the `freetype` dependency (this module really has an issue) and allowed the cross-compilation to complete successfully.

I'm still interested by a solution to the problem, but it probably involves generating or finding the library for the target and finding a way to feed it to the compiler in the flow, so it may be somewhat convoluted.

Comment: Have you looked into [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross)? It requires docker (or podman), and I'm not sure what the container situation on windows is; but on Linux cross is a godsend.

Comment: @MeetTitan No, I haven't, thanks for the tip! It's a completely different approach, so I'd rather first try to make it work with the current tools. Since it's already working in some cases, chances are it only requires a minimal modification.

Comment: Besides, from what I found, it's likely that the same issue will happen when using Docker. I think it's a problem with `freetype` because it requires installing a library first. Maybe it's not possible to cross-compile at all because of this.

Comment: You might have more joy using WSL to build the cross-tools.  I built `musl-cross-make` (to target the RG351 handheld) without issue under WSL and am moving onto rust next.

Comment: WSL works great for me to cross compile! Thank you for the detailed description in the question and the helping comments! If someone needs some help, ask. After over an hour of trying different things, this finally worked out!